# python pandas agg and count in same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have data in 2 columns and would like to group col 2 based on col 1 and create a new col 3 with their counts. I did,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("pairs.txt",sep='\t')
group = df.groupby(['COL_A'])['COL_B'].agg('-*-'.join)
group1 = df.groupby(['COL_A'])['COL_A'].count()
```

with this I clearly get group,

```
COL_A
A Cat-*-Rat-*-Mouse
B Monkey
C Tiger
D Squirrel
```

and group1:

```
COL_A
A 3
B 1
C 1
D 1
```

How to combine group and group1 into single line in more pythonic way such that my output is ?

```
COL_A    COL_B         COUNT
    A Cat-*-Rat-*-Mouse 3
    B Monkey            1
    C Tiger             1
    D Squirrel          1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
group = df.groupby(['COL_A']).agg({'COL_B': ['-*-'.join, 'count']})
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

declare your variables:

```
import pandas as pd

id = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
animals = [['Cat', 'Rat', 'Mouse'], ['Monkey'], ['Tiger'], ['Squirrel']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'COL_A': id, 'COL_B': animals})
df
```

result

```
  COL_A              COL_B
0     A  [Cat, Rat, Mouse]
1     B           [Monkey]
2     C            [Tiger]
3     D         [Squirrel]
```

explode COL_B

```
df_exp = df.explode('COL_B').reset_index()[['COL_A', 'COL_B']]
df_exp
```

result

```
  COL_A     COL_B
0     A       Cat
1     A       Rat
2     A     Mouse
3     B    Monkey
4     C     Tiger
5     D  Squirrel
```

now apply both functions

```
df_exp.groupby('COL_A').agg(
    {
        'COL_B': ['-*-'.join, 'count']
    }
).reset_index()
```

result

```
  COL_A              COL_B      
                      join count
0     A  Cat-*-Rat-*-Mouse     3
1     B             Monkey     1
2     C              Tiger     1
3     D           Squirrel     1
```